# Is there an Android Beam failure callback

Tags: android, callback, nfc, android-beam

I am trying to build an NFC enabled application that transmits data to another device via Android Beam (pushing a NDEFMessage).

While I know there is a success callback `void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent event)`, I can't find a failure callback, which would be really useful.
I tried to think of other way to sort of guess whether the transfer happened, if it succeeded or failed but cannot really find anything satisfying. Even a dirty timer would not work since I cannot know for sure when and even if the user actually starts the beam.

I feel pretty much bound by the API since the OS is handling most of the functionality and the application is only providing the message to send.

Any suggestions, something I might have missed? I'd rather avoid rooting the device if possible, but if it cannot be accomplished without tinkering with the core NFC code, then so be it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such callback. Or a notification or anything that would give you a clue that things didn't worked.

**Unfortunately.**

In general the Android Beam API has not been designed with error handling in mind.